# Sample() than make a dataframe. R

Tags: r, dataframe, sample

I want to Sample 100 times (with replacement) from the numbers 1 to 20 by using sample() then turn this data into a data frame and visualize it.

```
df <- sample(1:20, 100, replace=TRUE)
df <- as.data.frame(df)
ggplot(df, aes(x= df, y= n)) + geom_bar(position = "fill")
```

trying to find a better way to turn sample() data into a data frame. Thanks

Comment: You could use `df <- data.frame(x = sample(1:20, 100, replace = TRUE))`. It's not clear what you're trying to achieve in the `ggplot()` - a histogram maybe?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you mean by better way, but I guess you could do

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(x = sample(1:20, 100, replace=TRUE))
ggplot(df, aes(x)) + geom_bar()
```

Or use it directly

```
ggplot(data.frame(x = sample(1:20, 100, replace=TRUE)), aes(x)) + geom_bar()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A better option would be to make use of `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
tibble(x = sample(1:20, 100, replace = TRUE)) %>%
      ggplot(aes(x)) + 
      geom_bar()
```

[image]

---

In `base R`, we can do this without creating a data.frame

```
barplot(sample(1:20, 100, replace = TRUE))
```